# Am I using switch/case wrong here to control?

Tags: switch-statement, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I am trying to check the logs and depending the last log, run a different step in the transformation. Am I supposed to use some other steps or am I making another mistake here?
For example, if the query returns 1 I want execute SQL script to run, for 2 I want execute SQL script 2 to run and for 3 I want transformation to abort. But it keeps running all the steps even if only one value returns from the CONTROL step.

[The transformation looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuVQ1.png)

[And the switch/case step looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5s2K.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's correctly configured, but keep in mind that in a transformation all steps are initiated at the beginning of the transformation, waiting to receive the streaming data from the previous step. So the Abort and Execute script steps are going to be started as soon as the transformation is started, if they don't need data from the previous step to run, they are going to run at the beginning.

If you want the scripts to be executed depending on the result of the CONTROL output, you'll need to use a job, that runs the steps (actions) sequencially:

- A transformation runs the CONTROL step and afterwards you put a "Copy rows to result" step to make the data produced from the CONTROL step available to the job
- After the transformation, you use a "Simple evaluation" action in the job, to determine which script (or abort) to run. Jobs also have an "Execute SQL Script" action, so you can put it afterwards.

I'm supposing your CONTROL step only produces one row, if the output is more than one row, the "Simple evaluation" action won't do the job, you'll have to design one of various transformations to execute for each row of the previous transformation, running what you need.